# jQuery slider - Can't see the bottom of the page, browser scroll bar doesn't appear when the page is large

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider, scrollbar

Here is a working code when there are not too much text in the content part:
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wvGHL/)

The explanation, what is in there: centered content + sticky footer, everything slides down when the link clicked. Link slides down as well. Everything works fine, when the content part is rather small.

The same code is here [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dZu74/), the only difference from the first link is html content: I added too much text so you can see there is still no scroll bar to scroll down the page. You don't see the sticky footer. Why the scroll bar is not displayed? How to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CSS you have `overflow: hidden;` for the `#global-container` div that contains all your content. Because of that, any content that does not fit inside the div gets hidden.

Change it to `overflow: auto;` and you'll get a scroll bar once there is a lot of content.